# Nesting another Java If/Else statement to print out when a Wrong Character is Entered

Tags: java, java-io

So, I'm having an issue getting my program to print out `You must enter either C or F or Y or N` depending on the response that is inputted. I have tried putting other if-else statements inside the program, but it does not function correctly and breaks the for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Programmed by .");
        double standardCompact = 30.50;
        double couponCompact = ((30.50)-(30.50 * 0.07));
        double standardFullSize = 40.50;
        double couponFullSize = ((40.50)-(40.50 * 0.07));

        // Scanner Input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Rent a Car? [Y or N]: ");

        // Response String
        String response = input.next().toUpperCase();

        if (response.equals("N")) {
            System.out.println("You entered no. Bye.");
        }
        else if (response.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.print("Compact or Full-Size? [C or F]: ");
            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("C")) {
                System.out.println("You selected Compact.");

                //case1
                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is " + standardCompact + " per day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is " + couponCompact + " per day.");
                }
            }
            else if (response.equals("F")) {
                System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");

                //case 2
                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is " + standardFullSize + " per day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is " + couponFullSize + " per day.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `else`?

Comment: honestly not really, I'm still learning java and am pretty noobish here. So far i know If, Else if, Else which refers to the default correct?

Comment: You just need to add `else` clauses to two of your conditionals.  In the first conditional you check for `N` then for `Y`, well what if they entered `Z`?  Sounds like you need an `else`.  In the second conditional you check for `C` then for `F`, well what if they entered `X`?  Another spot the `else` could be used.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

When constructing an if statement, `else` can be used to handle all other conditions not caught by previous `if` or `else if` statements.

```
int x = 0;

if(x ==1){
    System.out.println("1");
}else if(x ==2){
   System.out.println("2");
}else{
  //execute if none of the other conditionals are true
  System.out.println("Other Conditions not met");
}

//Outputs:  Other Conditions not met
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a combination of a boolean flag, and 'else' statements. Therefore, if the user does not enter N or Y, set this flag to true. Similarly, if the user does not enter C or F, set this flag to true.

Later, at the end of the for-loop, check this flag. If it is true, print your message. This could be worth a try...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean notValidCharacter;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        notValidCharacter = false;

        System.out.println("Programmed by .");

        double standardCompact = 30.50;
        double couponCompact = ((30.50)-(30.50 * 0.07));
        double standardFullSize = 40.50;
        double couponFullSize = ((40.50)-(40.50 * 0.07));

        //Scanner Input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Rent a Car? [Y or N]: ");

        //Response String
        String response = input.next().toUpperCase();

        if (response.equals("N")){
            System.out.println("You entered no. Bye. ");
        }
        else if (response.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.print("Compact or Full-Size? [C or F]: ");

            response = input.next().toUpperCase();
            if (response.equals("C")) {
                System.out.println("You selected Compact. ");

                //case1
                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardCompact + " " + "per     day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponCompact + " " + "per day.");
                }
            }
            else if(response.equals("F")) {
                System.out.println("You have selected Full-Size. ");

                //case 2

                System.out.print("Have coupon? [Y or N]: ");
                response = input.next().toUpperCase();
                if (response.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + standardFullSize + " " +    "per day.");
                }
                else if (response.equals("Y")) {
                    System.out.println("Price is" + " " + couponFullSize + " " + "per day.");
                }
            }
            else {
                notValidCharacter = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            notValidCharacter = true;
        }

        if (notValidCharacter) {
            System.out.println("You must enter either C or F or Y or N");
        }
    }
}
```